# Inject custom feign client into Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, feign

I am currently trying to get a grip of both Spring and Feign.
Cutting straight to the point:
I am struggling to modify @FeignClient in this project:
[Feign Hello World by Walery](https://github.com/walery/feign-helloworld)
so as to instead of

> WikidataClient

```
@FeignClient(url = "https://www.wikidata.org/w")
// https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search=apple&language=en&format=json
public interface WikidataClient {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&language=en&format=json", method = GET)
    WebsearchEntities searchForEntities(@RequestParam("search") final String search);
}
```

use @Autowired notation similar to one found here: [Section called : Creating Feign Clients Manually](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html)

The purpose of this would be to inject custom decoder and encoder later on. I've been exprimenting with it for a while and all I managed to achieve was ruin the whole thing.

I gathered some clues from here and there and managed to come to the point where I created a Configuration class :

> FeignConfig

```
@Import(FeignClientsConfiguration.class)
public class FeignConfig {
    public WikidataClient fooclient;
    @Autowired
    public FeignConfig(Encoder encoder, Decoder decoder){
        this.fooclient = Feign.builder()
                .encoder(encoder)
                .decoder(decoder)
                .target(WikidataClient.class,"https://www.wikidata.org/w");
    }
}
```

Modified

> WikidataClient

interface slightly

```
//@FeignClient(url = "https://www.wikidata.org/w")
// https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search=apple&language=en&format=json
public interface WikidataClient {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&language=en&format=json", method = GET)
    WebsearchEntities searchForEntities(@RequestParam("search") final String search);
}
```

and tried to use aforementioned class instead

> WikidataRunner

```
@Component
public class WikidataRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final WikidataClient omdbClient;
    @Autowired
    public WikidataRunner(WikidataClient omdbClient){
        this.omdbClient = omdbClient;
        this.feignConfig = new FeignConfig(new Encoder.Default(), new Decoder.Default());
    }

    FeignConfig feignConfig;
    @Override
    public void run(final String... args) throws Exception {
        final WebsearchEntities apple = feignConfig.fooclient.searchForEntities("apple");
        System.out.println(apple);
    }
}
```

All I got were different kind of Bean errors

> 2017-07-19 08:02:29.056 ERROR 2018 --- Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'wikidataRunner' defined in file
>   [/home/mibi/IdeaProjects/FUFEign/feign-helloworld/target/classes/codes/walery/research/feign/wikidata/WikidataRunner.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type [codes.walery.research.feign.wikidata.WikidataClient]:
>   : No qualifying bean of type
>   [codes.walery.research.feign.wikidata.WikidataClient] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [codes.walery.research.feign.wikidata.WikidataClient] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {} [
>   main]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication                at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
>   : Application startup failed  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [codes.walery.research.feign.wikidata.WikidataClient] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1326)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1072)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:667)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:342)
>     ... 18 common frames omitted    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:273)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:980)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
>     at
>   codes.walery.research.feign.FeignHelloworldApplication.main(FeignHelloworldApplication.java:12)
>   Wrapped by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'wikidataRunner' defined in file
>   [/home/mibi/IdeaProjects/FUFEign/feign-helloworld/target/classes/codes/walery/research/feign/wikidata/WikidataRunner.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type [codes.walery.research.feign.wikidata.WikidataClient]:
>   : No qualifying bean of type
>   [codes.walery.research.feign.wikidata.WikidataClient] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [codes.walery.research.feign.wikidata.WikidataClient] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 beCaused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [codes.walery.research.feign.wikidata.WikidataClient] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1326)
>   an which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
>   Dependency annotations: {}    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1072)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   ... 18 more     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:667)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:342)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:273)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:980)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:969)
>   [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]   at
>   codes.walery.research.feign.FeignHelloworldApplication.main(FeignHelloworldApplication.java:12)
>   [classes/:na] 2017-07-19 08:02:29.059  INFO 2018 --- [       Thread-1]
>   s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3d8314f0:
>   startup date [Wed Jul 19 08:02:24 CEST 2017]; root of context
>   hierarchy
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I won't deny being novice at Spring and Feign. Thing is I need to undestand both of these desperately. So far I've spent 10+ hours researching about Feign to no avail.

Kindly asking for help and guidance

MissingBracket

Comment: We need to know what those "different" kind of errors are; we can't read your mind and solve a problem that you didn't describe.

Comment: Edited.
There is either one posted above or
"Failed to load application context"

Answer (score 0):

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> [codes.walery.research.feign.wikidata.WikidataClient] found for
> dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate for this dependency.

try to declare a bean somewhere:

```
    @Bean
    public WikiDataClient wikiDataClient () {

    }
```

Construct feign client with feign builder manually:

```
Feign.builder().client(client).encoder(encoder).decoder(decoder).contract(contract).target(WikiDataClient.class, "http://serviceId")
```